How can I create custom hex colors in Vimscript?
So I was trying to make a Vim colorscheme, but then I stumbled on a problem. There was this Vim colorscheme that was compatible for one terminal profile, but not on another. Here's the profile with the intended colors:

and here's the one without the intended colors:

How can I fix it?
I tried using guifg and guibg instead of ctermfg and ctermbg like this:
set termguicolors

but that didn't work because this is what came up:

Slight, yet noticeable.

:help 'termguicolors'?

Fix what, exactly? Both screenshots look good to me. Also, this is a programming forum: show us your code if you want us to help you fix it.

@romainl I want the colors on screenshot No. 1 to be the same on screenshot No. 2

Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose. Add details how exactly you used guifg etc. What exactly is the difference between the two terminal profiles. Does one of the screenshots show the default colors as if you did not specify your color scheme? Or could it be that the terminal supports only a limited set of colors and tries to approximate the specified colors as far as possible?

This is probably more appropriate to [vi.se] . Please delete here and repost there. Good luck.

We don't know what terminal emulator you use or your $TERM. There is no code, here. Nothing but perfectly fine screenshots. You are not even pointing at specific problems in those screenshots. If you are actually "trying to make a Vim colorscheme", then show it, at the very least, in order to make this question an actual programming question.
